# prolog list of all divisors of a number

Tags: prolog, primes

I want to find all the divisors of a natural number.and output a list.

now my code looks like this:

```
divisors(0,[]).
divisors(N,[N1|P]):- 
    N1=N,
    RES is (N mod N1),
    N1 is N-1, 
    RES==0,
    divisors(N,P).
divisors(N,[N1|P]):- 
    N1=N,
    RES is (N mod N1),
    N1 is N-1, 
    RES\=0,!, fail.
```

but it doesn't work. tell me, what am I doing wrong?
I've seen what can be done via **findall**, but I want to do it differently.The idea is as follows. Subtract one from the number (whose divisors we are looking for) each time and if the original number is divided by a new number, then write it to the head of the list.

(I just realized..That I don 't remember N anywhere ..since with recursive calls, it will already be different. I'm completely confused..)

Comment: Hint: Can use https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=divmod/4 (using a `Remainder` of 0) to get both divisors simultaneously.

Comment: Have a look through https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D+divisors

Comment: "*tell me, what am I doing wrong?*" - as soon as the number doesn't divide equally you flip the table and ragequit `RES\=0,!, fail.`  instead of carrying on counting down towards 0.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Yes, I've already noticed that.. but I do not know how to properly label "failure" so that the value is not written to the head of the list.

Comment: if the value does not belong to the head of the list you just don't put it there: `put([Val|T],R):- does_not_belong(Val), put(T,R).` `put([Val|T],[Val|R]):- does_belong(Val), put(T,R).`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *(I just realized..That I don 't remember `N` anywhere ..since with recursive calls, it will already be different. I'm completely confused..)*

That's right, there is no concept of nested scope in Prolog. Instead, we pass everything we need further down among the predicate's arguments, possibly using additional arguments.

*Minimal edit* to fix your code:

```
divisors(N,L):- divisors(N,N,L).

divisors(N,0,[]):- !.
divisors(N,N1,[N1|P]):-    % use N1
    %N1=N,
    RES is (N mod N1),
    N2 is N1-1, 
    RES==0,
    divisors(N,N2,P).      
divisors(N,N1,P):-         % skip N1
    %N1=N,
    RES is (N mod N1),
    N2 is N1-1, 
    RES\=0, %!, fail
    divisors(N,N2,P).      % same P
```

The result list `L` is instantiated in the top-down fashion.

Examples:

```
49 ?- divisors(12,L).
L = [12, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1].

50 ?- divisors(37,L).
L = [37, 1].
```

Answer (score 1):

The brute force way of finding all the divisors of a natural number would be something like this:

```
divisors( 0 , []  ) .  % zero is a special case
divisors( N , Ds  ) :- % otherwise, the general case applies
  integer(N),          % - N must be an integer, and
  N > 0,               % - N must be positive (and greater than 0)
  divisors(1,N,Ds)     % - invoke our helper predicate to try all possible divisors from 1–N inclusive
  .                    % - Easy!

divisors( D , N , [D|Ds] ) :- % case 1: D is a divisor of N
  D < N ,                     %   - D must be less than N, and
  0 =:= N mod D,              %   - D must be an integer divisor of N,
  !,                          %   - eliminate the choice point
  D1 is D+1,                  %   - increment D
  divisors(D1,N,Ds)           %   - recurse down, with D prepended to the result list
  .                           %
divisors( D , N ,    Ds  ) :- % case 2: D is not a divisor of N
  D < N ,                     %   - D must be less than N, and
  0 =\= N mod D,              %   - D must not be an integer divisor of N
  !,                          %   - eliminate the choice point
  D1 is D+1,                  %   - increment D
  divisors(D1,N,Ds) .         %   - recurse down, discarding the current D
divisors( N , N , [N]    )    % case 3: every number is its own divisor.
  .                           %
```